# Eventbased UART input on Raspberry with Linux

Tags: c++, linux, raspberry-pi3, irq, wiringpi

I want to port my project to new technological stack.

Current stack:

- C#
- UWP
- Windows IoT
- Raspberry Pi 3

New stack

- C++
- WiringPi
- Linux (may be Raspbean)
- Raspberry Pi 3

One of the reasons I want to do it: the loop I need to use for listen UART:

```
private async Task<byte> getByte()
{
    uint loaded = 0;

    do
    {
        loaded = await dataReaderObject.LoadAsync(1);
        Task.Delay(-1).Wait(10);
    } while (loaded == 0);

    return dataReaderObject.ReadByte();
}
```

However, what I found in WiringPi is something similar:

```
int serialGetchar (int fd) ;
```

> Returns the next character available on the serial device. This call will block for up to 10 seconds if no data is available (when it will return -1)

Gotten from [here](http://wiringpi.com/reference/serial-library/)

Is there something like follow code?

```
WiringPiCPPLib.UARTDataReceived += OnDataReceived;
void OnDataReceived(byte[] data) { ... }
```

I want event based UART handling rather than `while(true)` style.

Comment: I think things are going to be painful for you. Windows has a rich and unified API for waiting on objects and performing asynchronous tasks. Linux is a collections of sockets, signals and threads that you have to piece together. Serial programming is another ugly area of Linux. Linux has the primitives, you just need to provide the glue for the unification. [libevent](https://libevent.org/) may be of use to you, so you should familiarize yourself with it.

Comment: So I don't have such API here in this case for UWP...

Comment: The name `WiringPi` is all new to me, but if you want to get rid of the blocking read loop, won't some sort of `select(2)` or `poll(2)` system calls do under linux?